# Iterating through Beautiful Soup

Tags: for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of urls and I am trying to scrape each of them to output in a single data frame. my code is below:

```
res=[]
    for link in url_list:
        html = urlopen(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
        headers = headers[1:]
        rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]
        player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
                for i in range(len(rows))]
        stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
```

I only get output for one web page. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your dataframe each time in your for loop. If you have a lot of pages, you can collect the individual dataframes and concatenate them.

```
df_hold_list = []
for link in url_list:
    html = urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
    headers = headers[1:]
    rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
            for i in range(len(rows))]
    df_hold_list.append(pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers))

stats = pd.concat(df_hold_list)
```